# JQuery not posting to Express backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, post, express

I have a program that was working before and when I ran it today, the post seems to not be getting to the server. I added an alert to debug, and it runs successfully. Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(d) {
        d.preventDefault();
        var data = {"message" : $("#theText").val()};
        alert($("#theText").val());
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/post",
           processData: false,
           contentType: "application/json",
           data: JSON.stringify(data),
           dataType: text
          });
     });
});
```

It is being passed into an Express route that just looks like this:

```
app.post("/post", log, dc);
```

It does not show up on the logger at all, and even if I change it to something like this it still doesn't print:

```
app.post("/post", function(){
    console.log("received post");
    });
```

Comment: Good first post! A small critique, if you can always try to clarify your question in the body of your post. Just for good measure. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a named variable to dataType...should be a string like `'json'` or `'text'`. That is probably causing the primary error.